# Instagram Graph API - reels available but what is the format?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Facebook mentioned they're now making reels data available with the /insights endpoint, yay (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2022/06/27/introducing-reels-apis-to-instagram-platform/) )!
Although the article says they've updated their docs I don't see how it would be formatted, do we think the format will be like this?

```
insta_page_id/insights?metric=reels&period=lifetime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reels post in Instagram, you can try the following query in the Meta Graph API explorer(Assuming you have an app with required permissions):

[IGpost-id]/insights?metric=likes, comments, shares, plays,reach,saved,total_interactions

The above query should give you a response for these metric.

Currently I did not find any media_type as "reels". A reels media_type is still tagged as Video. Only way to identify if a post is a reel is through the permalink url which contains https://www.instagram.com/**reel**/XXXXXXX in it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights/

Comment: thanks for responding, yes for media_type I don't see any "reels" coming through,but if reel is coming through as video then how can we differentiate between whether its a reel or video?

Comment: Oh Actually I just checked and its in the media endpoint, where media_product_type = 'REELS'! I was looking at media_type but like you said its still Video

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @KristiLuna's comment above I was able to solve a similar problem.

Instagram reels are still identified by the Instagram Graph API as `media_type: "VIDEO"`. The way to tell the difference between a feed video and a reel is by checking the `media_product_type` field on the Graph API.

My approach (to loop through an Instagram user's media):

```js
fetch (`https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/${ig-user-id}/media?fields=id,media_type,media_product_type`, {method: 'get'})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  let dataObject = data.data
  dataObject.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (dataObject[i].media_type === "VIDEO" && dataObject[i].media_product_type === "REELS") {
      // do stuff 
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: yay glad to hear!